# Why is displaying 'command not found' by type 'npx create-react-app my-app' in terminal?

Tags: reactjs

when I type npx-create-react-app my-app in terminal for creating my react project  but that would tell me npx command not found ?[showing error npx command not found in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDQQN.png)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to solve this issue:

```js
npx clear-npx-cache
```

If the error is not resolved, you can force the command to use the latest version of 'create-react-app':

```js
npx create-react-app@latest <app-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be facing issues due to following reason

1. Your username has space in between Raheel Ahmed, if possible you can create new user in windows and have username without space.
2. Powershell some time through error related to permission, if you cmd or best is [git bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads)
3. You would need to have LTS version of Node.js installed, I think you might be having that.

I would recommend trying 2nd option first, that is installing git bash and try running the command there.

If that also does not work then give 1st option a try.